# How To Join in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables to be joined.

`Table 1` is a master table and contains a unique set of rows.

```
ID DESCRIPTION
01 Alpha
02 Gamma
03 Delta
04 Beta
```

`Table 2` is a detail table containing many rows with only some of the rows matching the master table.

```
ID   INFO MASTER_ID
0001 abc  02
0002 def  02
0004 xyz  01
0005 mno  04
```

I want to JOIN the tables in order to produce the following result:

```
Alpha "has detail"
Gamma "has detail"
Delta "does not have detail"
Beta "has detail"
```

Rather than:

```
Alpha "has detail"
Gamma "has detail"
Gamma "has detail"
Delta "does not have detail"
Beta "has detail"
```

The later output is returning Gamma twice and I only want it returned once.

I tried LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN and none of them produce my desired result.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` probably you are missing something

```
SELECT  CONCAT(a. description, IF(b.master_ID IS NOT NULL, ' has detail',' does not have detail'))
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT master_ID FROM table2) b
            ON a.ID = b.master_ID
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e302e/1)
- [**SQLFIDDLE Demo** (*with double quotes*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e302e/2)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.DESCRIPTION,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.MASTER_ID=Table1.ID)
            THEN 'has detail'
            ELSE 'does not have detail'
        END
    ) AS has
FROM
    Table1
```

Comment: I am sure your solution would work @Arion, but I did not try it. I saw `John Woo`'s answer first and tried it out. I embedded it into my code and it worked. So I prefer to move on with that solution. Thanks for offering your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different approach:

```
SELECT
  table1.description,
  IF((EXISTS(SELECT master_id from table2  where table2.master_id = table1.id)),
    'has detail',
    'does not have detail') As Status
FROM table1
```

Comment: I am curious about your solution @fthiella. If you do not use a JOIN but use your query statement, are you not reading table 2 for each and every row processed in table 1 -- hence maybe a bit less efficient in processing?

Comment: Joins are often faster than subquery, but not always. In this case i can't be sure, but i guess that this solution might be less efficient than others. But it's very easy to read and you immediately know what it's doing!

Comment: Agreed @fthiella -- it caught my attention due to the streamlined and condensed coding of the query. I was just thinking it may not be most efficient due to how table 2 is processed against table 1. Nonetheless, as I stated a bit before you posted, I found and implemented a solution that gets me what I need so I am moving on. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Description, IF(b.Info, "has detail", "does not have detail") as Status
FROM Table_1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 b
ON a.MASTER_ID = b.MASTER_ID
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your output containts the detail part, then you have to either see both rows (as it'sa  valid result) or you need to aggregate the results by selecting FIRST, MAX, etc.

If you don't need the detail values themselves, then alternative would be to do two SELECTs and use UNION:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Description, "does not have detail" as Comment
    FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.ID = MASTER_ID)
    WHERE Table2.id IS NULL

    UNION 

    SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Description, "has detail" as Comment
    FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.ID = MASTER_ID)
    WHERE Table2.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using a groupby

```
SELECT a.Description, IF(count(b.id) > 0, "has detail", "does not have detail") as Status
FROM Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
ON a.iD = b.MASTER_ID
GROUP BY a.Description ORDER BY a.Description ASC
```